# Not able to set xml string to jvm property

Tags: java

Can I set xml as value to a jvm property ? Actually I have used a simulator in my java code and simulator is sending a xml as response and I have used a jvm property inside the simulator but I am not able to set the xml to that jvm property. So, Is there any way that I can set the xml to the jvm property?

Thanks in advance for guiding me.

```java
public String callSimulator()
{   

        String returnVal = System.getProperty(siebelJVMProp, responseXml);
}
```

Comment: Theoretically yes, but newlines are going to make it a pain. More typically, you use a property to specify a file that has the XML in it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to produce a small example that works, but using it is a pain:

```
class XmlTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("xmlTest", "<someXml/>"));
    }
}
```

Running it with

```
java XmlTest
```

produces

```
<someXml/>
```

and running it with

```
java -DxmlTest="<otherXml/>" XmlTest
```

produces

```
<otherXml/>
```

But for any more complex XML this soon gets unwieldy (imagine to have to quote some complex XML containing line breaks and quotes!)